# Mongodb Insert data API no respone

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need an API to insert data from android to mongodb , I follow [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/) ,the code can run , have NO error , and I use POSTMAN try to post some data , it always say could not get any respone , seem to have an error connecting to 192.168.1.105:3000/songs
but I can use find all api and findByID.
This took me hours , please help , so depress :(

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

songs = require('./routes/route');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/songs', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});


app.get('/songs',songs.findAll);
app.get('/findById/:id',songs.findById);
app.get('/songs',songs.addSong);
```

route

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = "mongodb://XXXX:XXXX@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;
var body = require('body-parser');


db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
db.once('open', function() {
console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
db.collection('songs',function(err, collection) {
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
  res.send(items);
  });
  });
  };


exports.findById = function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log('Retrieving song: ' + id);
db.collection('songs', function(err, collection)
collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
  res.send(item);
 });
 });
 };


exports.addSong = function(req, res) {
var song = req.query;
 console.log('Adding song: ' + JSON.stringify(song));
db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
collection.insert(song, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
{console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
res.send(result[0]);

}
});
});
};
```

Comment: Can you fix the indenting in your code? It's really hard to read.

Comment: @JohnnyHK OK , i do my best ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I changed a few things in your code. I'm successfully getting the request body in the app.js file. Do have a look at the code.

**route.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;
var body = require('body-parser');
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
//db = mongoose.connection.db;
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});

exports.addSong = function(req, res) {
 var song = req.body;
 console.log('Adding song: ' + JSON.stringify(song));
 db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
     collection.insert(song, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
      } else {
        console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
        res.send(result[0]);
      }
    });
});
}
```

**Notice that I have changed the URI to localhost, so change it again to the one you specified.**

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
songs = require('./routes/route');

app.post('/songs', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Request.Body : " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    songs.addSong(req, res);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

app.get('/songs',songs.addSong);
```

Since your only problem was that you weren't able to get the request body. You'll be able to get it with this code.

Also since your `app.get('/songs',songs.addSong);` is of type **GET**, you'll not be able to send **POST Data** through it. So change it to

`app.post('/songs',songs.addSong);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: it WORKS! oh my god, you made my day!